# Javascript addEventListener from a given function string name as an argument

Tags: javascript

How can you set an event listener to a control with a string variable name instead of function argument name?

```
//working method
var elementValue = document.createElement("button");
elementValue.className = "locatorTrainButton";
elementValue.addEventListener('click', myFunctionName_OnClick);

//set event from variable name
var stringName = "myFunctionName_OnClick";
elementValue.addEventListener('click', *stringName??*);
```

Comment: It has to be a function, otherwise you get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.`

Comment: Take a look at: ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530), it might give you an idea how you might use a string as an object key, and a function as a value which you can then use as the second argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your function is defined at the top level then you can do like:

```js
function test(){
  console.log('worked');
}
addEventListener('click', window['test']);
```

```html
Just click the window!
```

If your function is nested then you can assign it to window, just make sure your calls are below assignment when using function variable declaration:

```js
(()=>{
window.test = ()=>{
  console.log('worked');
}
})();
(()=>{
addEventListener('click', window['test']);
})();
```

```html
Just click the window!
```

Comment: I think OP has a String that they want to use as a function they can execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because the `listener` must be an object or a function

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> `addEventListener()` works by adding a function or an object that implements `EventListener` to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the `EventTarget` on which it's called.

Here is the syntax:

> `target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);`
>
> `target.addEventListener(type, listener [, useCapture])`;

Where `listener` is:

> The object that receives a notification (an object that implements the `Event` interface) when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the `EventListener` interface, or a JavaScript function.

Comment: Thank you. Ok that has to be a function or an object, but isn't there a method to relate the object with its name as a variable? So, var listener = objectFromStringName(name); elementValue.addEventListener('click', listener);

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible unless you use  `eval` (which is already answered)

Comment: The window['name'] works for me in this case. Thank you for the detailed explanation and workaround

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a string name as a function reference in the callback. However, using an anonymous function with `eval()` may work, although not recommended.

That is because *technically* speaking you can use `eval()` to invoke a function by its name and then use `<functionName>.apply(null, arguments)` to call it with the same arguments the callback receives.

However, I would not recommend this solution because `eval()` in general is frowned upon as it presents security risks. Is there a reason why you want to use a dynamic function name?

```js
function myFunctionName_OnClick(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
  
  // Verify that event is passed correctly
  console.log(e.target);
}

var elementValue = document.createElement("button");
elementValue.innerText = 'Click me!';

var stringName = "myFunctionName_OnClick";
elementValue.addEventListener('click', function() {
  eval(stringName + '.apply(null, arguments)');
});

document.body.appendChild(elementValue);
```

Comment: this is still a function in the listener

Comment: @dippas Yes, that is unfortunately the case.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I am defining the controls dynamically with a general function for a code optimization. So the different controls must point into different event functions. eval() works too, beside the risks. Thanks